# specify a maven2 dependency version from the commandline

Tags: maven, maven-2

I'm working a contract that has some build oddities... they're using maven, but the pom file is actually edited by the build script to replace the version number with the jenkins build number, and then that same number is used to replace the version of other internal projects which will be used at build time by this project.  I am new to maven, but know enough to know this feels wrong.

I can pass in the version number, but putting the same property in the dependency block doesn't seem to work.

I know the tao of maven is serious business, please understand this is a very short term contract and build system isn't in my statement of work - I just want to get to a place where the source controlled files aren't edited by the simple act of running a build.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "putting the same property in the dependency block doesn't seem to work"? Perhaps show an example of what you tried. There's no obvious reason why that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely define a Maven property with a version value, and reference it in the dependency declaration.  And, with Maven properties, they can be passed into maven using the "-D" command line option.

What I'm not sure of it whether the timing of how Maven runs will allow this to change the dependency version.  I think (so, I'm not 100% certain) that the dependency management will be managed before command-line options are processed.

I'd try defining a maven property with the dependency version in it, and reference the maven property in the dependency declaration appropriately.  Then, when running mvn, supply the desired version as a property value.  That'd be the most-likely approach.